# Dirichlet distribution and its applications in data science

Tags: stochastic-processes, markov-process, random-walk

What is the Dirichlet distribution and what are its applications?

Comment: I basically dont understand the applications of the Dirichlet distribution in the context of numerical simulations.

Comment: What is that you don't understand? What do you want to combine and why? Please edit to make your question more clear.

Comment: I hope that is clear

Comment: Sorry, but it is still unclear. Moreover, if your problem is that you don't understand documentation of `numpy.random.dirichlet`, then it's off-topic on this site since we do not provide help on using Python (see http://stats.stackexchange.com/help/on-topic)

Comment: How about that?

Comment: At best people might be able to give a few of the applications

Comment: Hmm is there not enough research into this?

Comment: Did you read the wikipedia page? Do you have any specific questions after reading it? https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dirichlet_distribution

Comment: @Akram There are literally thousands of applications and potential applications. If you want more than just a few applications, your question is too broad and will be closed. It's up to you, but if a few applications isn't sufficient for you your question won't be suitable for our site.

Answer (score 1):

A Dirichlet distribution is a vector-valued continuous distribution whose components are in (0,1) and which sum to 1.

Consider a situation where $X_1\sim\text{Beta}(\alpha_1,\alpha_2)$ and $X_2=1-X_1$. Then $\mathbf{X}=(X_1,X_2)^\prime$ is the simplest case of a Dirichlet distribution, but more typically $\mathbf X$ will be of dimension $3$ or more.

It generalizes the Beta distribution (which is commonly used to model continuous proportions) to the situation where some whole is made up of multiple proportions of interest (e.g. the proportions of the various components in some mixture, such as the proportions of different soil types in a region, or the proportion of various ingredients in some mixture (such as a shampoo, say), or the proportions of a document on each of several topics. That is, it is a common choice for [compositional data](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Compositional_data).

This distribution has the [density](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dirichlet_distribution#Probability_density_function)

$f(\mathbf{x};\,\mathbf{\alpha})=\frac{x_1^{\alpha_1-1}\,x_2^{\alpha_2-1}\,...\,x_k^{\alpha_k-1}}{\mathbf{B}(\mathbf{\alpha)}}\,,\: 0<x_i<1\,,\sum_i x_i=1\,,\alpha_i>0$

where $\mathbf{B}(\mathbf{\alpha})=\frac{\Gamma(\alpha_1)\Gamma(\alpha_2)...\Gamma(\alpha_k)}{\Gamma(\alpha_1+\alpha_2+...+\alpha_k)}$

Another common use for the Dirichlet is as a prior distribution on the multinomial in Bayesian statistics.